# What’s happened to civismtp?

Tags: civimail, smtp

They’ve been great for years but I applied for an account 5 days ago and heard nothing. Also no response to query email sent to all 3 of their email addresses.
Are they still in business?

Comment: Hi CiviSMTP is a provider and this stackexchange can help you with civicrm development and configuration only - So, I guess try to contact CiviSMTP again - Thanks

Comment: Hi Lesley, I've had the same experience over the past year. 
Applied for 2 accounts. Never heard back.
No response to contact requests either.
The clients who are currently using their service is still running though.